# Problema al subir imagen a Firebase Storage

Tags: android-studio, firebase, kotlin

Estoy siguiendo un Tutorial de como subir una foto a Firebase Storage pero me surgieron errores en el código que no puedo solucionar y en el video no explican como. La idea es que al apretar al botón se abra la galería y selecciones una imagen que será subida a Firebase Storage de allí la podre usar como foto de perfil.

Aqui esta mi codigo del Activity

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import com.google.firebase.firestore.SetOptions
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_edit_profile.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_register.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_gallery.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_gallery.editTextDireccion

class EditProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val File = 1
    private val database = Firebase.database
    val myRef = database.getReference("users")


    private val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile)


        Setup()
    }

    private fun Setup() {
        title = "Editar perfil"

        val user = intent.extras?.getString("emailcuenta")

        db.collection("user").document(user.toString()).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            nameEP.setText(it.get("Nombre") as String?)
            apellidoEP.setText(it.get("Apellido") as String?)
            direccionEP.setText(it.get("Direccion") as String?)
        }




        guardarButton.setOnClickListener {

            val data = hashMapOf("Nombre" to nameEP.text.toString(), "Apellido" to apellidoEP.text.toString(), "Direccion" to direccionEP.text.toString())


            db.collection("user").document(user.toString()).set(data, SetOptions.merge())
            onBackPressed()
        }

        cancelarButton.setOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }

        editPhotoButton.setOnClickListener {
            subirImagen()

        }

    }// Resto del codigo donde se llama a la Funcion subirImagen

    fun subirImagen(){
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.type = "image/"
        startActivityForResult(intent, File)

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == File) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                val FileUri = data!!.data
                val Folder: StorageReference =
                        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("usuarios")
                val file_name: StorageReference = Folder.child("file" + FileUri!!.LastPathSegment)
                file_name.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                    val hashMap =
                            HashMap<String, String>()
                    hashMap["link"] = java.lang.String.valueOf(uri)
                    myRef.setValue(hashMap)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Los Errores que me saltan al compilar y en rojo en el codigo son:

```
Unresolved reference: Firebase

Unresolved reference: LastPathSegment
```

Por las dudas aquí les paso el tutorial que seguí : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUC9BILIbJ8&t=650s

Si me pueden decir como solucionarlo o decirme como es la forma correcta de hacerlo se los agradecería mucho

Comment: Bienvenido! Mira el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para conocer mejor el sitio y ganar tu primera medalla.

Answer (score 0):

`Unresolved reference` significa que lo que intentas llamar no existe. Puede ser que esté mal escrito, que no lo hayas importado en ese archivo (esto es poco probable porque android studio lo hace automáticamente) o que esté en una librería que hayas olvidado agregar en tus dependencias.

El error en `LastPathSegment` es porque debe comenzar con minuscula: `lastPathSegment`

El objeto `Firebase` viene en las extensiones de firebase para kotlin (ktx). Para solucionar el error declara esta dependencia en tu archivo `build.gralde`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
```

Es posible que la tengas declarada sin el `-ktx`, de ser así simplemente editala. No la declares de nuevo.

Luego android studio debería ser capaz que importarlo en el archivo que lo estabas usando. Si no lo hace, agregalo manualmente:
`import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase`